# Ruby Hash default value {} vs hash.new

Tags: ruby

so I was wondering why this works:

```
new_hash = hash.new(0)
```

but this doesn't work:

```
new_hash = {0}
```

I hate inconsistency and I like to write with (), [], and {} whenever I get the hang of it because it simply looks cleaner to me.
I am aware that I could set a default value by calling new_hash.default = 0, but its just not as elegant.

edit: Am I missing something? Is there a way to use the syntax like that after all?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You already noticed that your second example is invalid Ruby. You wonder why? Because that is the way how the Ruby syntax was defined.

Comment: You are right. In the end I guess I was wondering if I missed something. A way you could actually use the syntax like that.

Comment: Where is the "inconsistency"? What you've proposed is *new, alternative syntax*; if you feel strongly that this would improve the language, you can suggest it to the ruby developers (or even try to add the feature yourself). But personally, I'd say that this would just add more confusion and complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two are equivalent:

```
h = Hash.new
```

```
h = {}
```

And these two are equivalent:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

```
h = {}
h.default_value = 0
```

The positional argument you pass to [`Hash.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#new-method) sets its [default value](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#class-Hash-label-Default+Values). (a block argument sets its default proc)

There's no shorthand to set a default value when using the hash literal syntax.